# How to restrict access to an AWS S3 bucket only to a specific role?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam

In my AWS project, I have a lambda function, called by an API in API Gateway, that gets a file in a S3 bucket.

I try to secure my S3 bucket as much as possible, and after reading [this](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/blogs/security/how-to-restrict-amazon-s3-bucket-access-to-a-specific-iam-role/) and [this](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/explicit-deny-principal-elements-s3/), here is what I did in my CloudFormation template:

- in the policy of the IAM role of the API:

```
  - Effect: 'Allow'
    Action:
      - "s3:GetObject"
    Resource: 'arn:aws:s3:::exampleS3Bucket/*'
```

- and in the policy of my S3 bucket:

```
  - Effect: "Deny"
    Action:
      - "s3:*"
    Principal: "*"
    Resource:
      - 'arn:aws:s3:::exampleS3Bucket'
      - 'arn:aws:s3:::exampleS3Bucket/*'
    Condition:
      StringNotLike:
        aws:userId:
          - "<API_IAM_ROLE_ID>"
```

According to the documentation, you can retrieve the `API_IAM_ROLE_ID` by calling the following AWS CLI command: `aws iam get-role --role-name <YOUR_IAM_ROLE>`.

But I face two issues:

- it doesn't work, I still have an `Access Denied` error
- even if it works, it does not look like a clean solution, especially if I want to deal with multiple environments (dev, staging, prod...)

**EDIT**

I also tried the following S3 bucket policy:

```
  - Effect: "Deny"
    Action:
      - "s3:*"
    NotPrincipal:
      AWS:
        - "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:root"
        - "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/my-api-role"
    Resource:
      - 'arn:aws:s3:::exampleS3Bucket'
      - 'arn:aws:s3:::exampleS3Bucket/*'
```

But when I call my API, that calls a lambda that calls S3.GetObject(), I still have an "Access Denied" exception.

How can I fix that?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you base that policy on the advice at https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-restrict-amazon-s3-bucket-access-to-a-specific-iam-role/?

Comment: @jarmod, yes, as I said in my post, but it's actually pretty hard to understand...

Comment: what doesn't work

Comment: @ArunK As I said in my post, I got a "Access Denied" error. But if I remove the S3 bucket policy, it works fine. But it's not the safest configuration.

Comment: when you say it doesn't work for you. is it not working for the `IAM user` who assumed the role and got temporary credentials?

Comment: because it's working for me with the bucket policy. it doesn't work for my IAM user, works if i assume the role

Comment: Why are you using the `Deny` policy? Are you specifically wanting to block access that might have been provided via a different policy (eg Admin users)? When you say "restrict access", what are you wanting to restrict from whom? For example, is it okay for people who have otherwise been granted access to List the contents of the bucket?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yes, I want to block access that might have been provided via a different policy. In the end, I only want to allow access (in the `Deny` block) to the API and a few admin IAM users.

Comment: So, the current situation seems to be that your `NotPrincipal` does not appear to be working correctly. If you were to remove this Deny bucket policy, can the Lambda function successfully access the object? If so, then we know that the Deny is the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Denying access to a particular bucket can be tricky.

For example, Admins might have the ability to modify Roles and Bucket Policies, so they would be able to regain access to the bucket.

A common practice is to **put sensitive information in a bucket in a different AWS Account**, then provide access to the bucket only to specific users in the 'main' account. This way, the default is that nobody in the main account has access. It also simplifies the design of permissions, since there is no need to apply `Deny` policies.

An example would be where sensitive HR information is being stored, where only a small number of users should have access to the data.

Answer (score 1):

this is how i did it recently.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::MyExampleBucket",
        "arn:aws:s3:::MyExampleBucket/*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringNotLike": {
          "aws:userId": [
            "AROAEXAMPLEID:*",
            "ACCOUNT NUMBER"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

this is how it works.

- Allow: the user's IAM policy allows access to S3 bucket
- Deny: bucket policy is used to deny access to all the users except the user id of the role.

to get the user id of the role:

```
aws iam get-role --role-name ROLE-NAME
```

reference:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-restrict-amazon-s3-bucket-access-to-a-specific-iam-role/